How to train for example 8 models, each in one specific GPU, in parallel?
I have access to a cluster of multiple nodes and GPUs. I want to train 15k models (for benchmarking).
What do you think is the best way to do that? I thought about training each model in one GPU, in parallel
How can I do this affectation? Using pytorch / SLURM
I tried DDP, and other parallelism techniques
